# AutoResizingMaskFlexibleWidth max width?

Tags: ios, resize, uitextfield, mask

In my app I have a UITextField in a UITableViewCell and currently I have it take up the entire width of the cell because obviously that would be the max it could go.

Anyway, is I know there is the option of using an autoresizingMask like:  AutoReszingMaskFlexibleWidth

Anyway, *first question*, so even if I set the width to lets say 1 in Interface Builder, the UITextField will adjust the width to the width of the text correct?

*Second question*, is there a way to make a max for the width of the autoresizing mask so that the width doesn't lets say get to 5000?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question: no.  If you set the width to 1, the text field will initially have width 1.  If, after the text field has been added as a subview of the table view cell, the table view cell's width is changed, the text field's width will also change.  Read [“Handling Layout Changes Automatically Using Autoresizing Rules” in the *View Programming Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5).

Second question: autoresizing doesn't support setting a max width.  If you need to enforce a max width, make a subclass of `UITableViewCell`, override `layoutSubviews` in your subclass, and enforce the maximum width in code.

Answer (score 1):

Autoresizing means that the view will change size (in your case width) as the superview resizes. If you've set a view to have a fixed distance to the edges and a flexible width then it will become 100 pixels wider as the superview becomes 100 pixels wider. It doesn't mean that it will automatically cover the entire width.

Also, autoresizing masks only say that the view's size should be flexible not how big/small it should be. You should (maybe wait for iOS 6 and) look at Auto Layout if you want to do those kinds of configurations. (No, it's not under NDA since it was on the WWDC keynote slides)

If you wan't custom control of the text fields size then you should override `layoutSubviews` on a custom UITableViewCell.